# How to convert struct to json without key for restAPI

Tags: json, go, struct

Golang Design Response Struct For API

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Optional map[string]interface{}

type Problem struct {
    Name               string
    Description        string
}

type ProblemResponse struct {
    Name               string `json:"name"`
    Description        string `json:"description"`
    Optional
}

func (problem *Problem) ToRes() *ProblemResponse {
    return &ProblemResponse{
        Name: problem.Name,
        Description: problem.Description,
    }
}

func main() {
    problem := Problem{"StackOverflow", "Asking Question"}
    problemRes := problem.ToRes()
    problemRes.Optional = make(map[string]interface{})
    problemRes.Optional["url"] = "https://stackoverflow.com"

    Response(*problemRes)
}

func Response(obj interface{}) {
    data, _ := json.Marshal(obj)
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

The code above will print

```
{
  "name": "StackOverflow",
  "description": "Asking Question",
  "Optional": {
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com"
  }
}
```

But what i want is this

```
{
  "name": "StackOverflow",
  "description": "Asking Question",
  "url": "https://stackoverflow.com"
}
```

I want in the main function i can append some information to json response. Any solution for this design, it prefer that we don't change Response Function. Thank in advance !!

Answer (score 2):

You could implement `json.Marshaler` interface on your `ProblemResponse` struct, converting everything to a flat map and encoding to JSON. If a type implements `json.Marshaler` interface, the json encoder will run the MarshalJSON method instead. Here is the documentation: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler

Example:

```golang
type Optional map[string]interface{}

type Problem struct {
    Name               string
    Description        string
}

type ProblemResponse struct {
    Name               string `json:"name"`
    Description        string `json:"description"`
    Optional
}

func (p *ProblemResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {

    // we create a flat map including problem's field and optional fields
    // we copy optional first to make sure name and description are not being overwritten from the optional map
    var m = make(map[string]interface{}, 2 + len(p.Optional))
    for k, v := range p.Optional {
        m[k] = v 
    } 
    m["name"] = p.Name
    m["description"] = p.Description 

    return json.Marshal(m)
}
```

If you don't care about modifying `Optional`, you could optimize by doing it `in place`:

```golang
func (p *ProblemResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    p.Optional["name"] = p.Name
    p.Optional["description"] = p.Description 

    return json.Marshal(p.Optional)
}
```

You could write a code generator if you have multiple structure that would need to implement that kind of `flattening` behaviour on MarshalJSON.

Alternatively you could use reflection and do something like that (you should complete this method by doing more checks and use json tag), I don't recommend that solution as you loose type safety:

```golang
func Flatten(s interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
        v := reflect.ValueOf(s)
        if v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
                v = v.Elem()
        }
        if v.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
                panic(fmt.Errorf("expect struct %T given", s))
        }

        t := v.Type()
        nField := t.NumField()
        r := v.FieldByName("Optional").Interface().(Optional)

        for i := 0; i < nField; i++ {
                f := t.Field(i)
                if f.Name != "Optional" {
                        fv := v.Field(i)
                        // here you could read json tags
                        // to get the value in the json tag instead of ToLower
                        r[strings.ToLower(f.Name)] = fv.Interface()
                }
        }

        return r
}

// usage
b, err i:= json.Marshal(Flatten(problemRes))
```

Or maybe just use a map ?

Comment: There are a lot of struct Response like ProblemResponse, If every struct implement this function, so it speed a lot of time

Comment: I added an example with a function using reflection to flatten your structure. You should improve it.

Comment: yes i think using map is the best, but the old source that all implement this way. So maybe one day i have to convert all of it to map. Thank you!!